# Method overloading in Laravel even tho my class is being extended

Tags: php, laravel, methods

Hi just like the title mentiones Im trying to use `BaseServiceClass` and `ChildServiceClass` in my service.
I wanna make this method: `makePost (PostObject $postObject){}` in `ChildServiceClass` which extends `BaseServiceClass`.

In BaseServiceClass I have defined `makePost` as such: `makePost (PostObject $postObject){}`

As for `PostObject` it extends `BaseObject` but I get this error when I try to set these Objects to parent and child I get that `ChildServiceClass:makePost() is not compatible with method BaseServiceClass:makePost()`

Example:

In Base service:

```
public function addFilter(BaseSearchObject $searchObject, $query){
    return $query;
}
```

In ProductService:

```
public function addFilter(ProductSearchObject $searchObject, $query)
    {
       //code that overrites BaseController
    }
```

as for the search objects:

```
class ProductSearchObject extends BaseSearchObject
```

Is there a way I can pass different classes to these methods?

Comment: from what you say the 2 classes parameters signature are the same, ```makePost (PostObject $postObject)``` which should not lead to the error. maybe i would post the actual code

Comment: @suxgri thx for replying, cant do such a thing bcs of NDA. The 2 parameters are different one contains BaseObject the other one PostObject. Keep in mind that PostObject extends BaseObject

Comment: ok so that why, they have to be the same, but you can make it work if they accept the same interface instead of the 2 concrete objects

Comment: Not what Im trying to do, I'm trying to make BaseController where in other services I can just pass their Classes, for instance in ChildClassOneService I will pass PostObject, in ChildaClassTwoService I'll pass lets say PhoneObject etc...

Comment: @TimLewis ok I passed my actual code (edited), Im sorry if I looked like I was pushing away people that try to help, that was not my intention

Comment: All good; I appreciate the follow-up, and I've seen way worse on here. Now it's a lot more clear; your original question had `PostObject $postObject` for both, but your actual code shows `BaseSearchObject $searchObject` and `ProductSearchObject $searchObject`, which are definitely different (which you alluded to in the comments, but clearly I missed that ‍♂️). The answer below shows a good approach, and you could simply omit or generalize the type definition, like `Object $searchObject` or `$searchObject`, etc.

Comment: Read about covariance vs contravariance and why PHP and many other languages allow you to extend a function to take more **broad** parameters and return more **narrow** parameters, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is very simple, you are trying to overwrite a method with `PostObject` that originally accepts a `BaseObject`.

The fact that `PostObject` extends `BaseObject` has nothing to do here, since a `PostObject` is never a `BaseObject`, it is always more than a `BaseObject`, but a `BaseObject` can sometimes be a `PostObject`.

The solution is to not use any of these objects, but have the object implement a common interface like `IsServicable` and have all methods accept an object that implements this interface rather than a concrete type.

If using php8 you can also use union types. In this case you make both services accept both types of inputs.

```php
public function makePost(BaseObject|PostObject $object){}
```